# Acrylic shower base with tile bench?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, tiling

Is there any reason not to use a prefab acrylic shower base with tile walls and a tile bench?  I get that tile walls and a prefab acrylic base are a common combo, but I don't see anyone adding a tile bench.

My thinking is we're remodeling both bathrooms in our house while living in it. We just finished the first one and just did the best things and spent the most time and money. We'd like this one to go quick and cheap. It's an odd sized space, so I'm still going to do a tile shower, but I'd like to avoid constructing the base. There's a place nearby selling acrylic  bases for only $25 which will beat both the cost and time of making a custom shower pan.

This is one of the only pictures I was able to find on the internet that looked like the combo I'm thinking of-- tile walls & bench with acrylic base (or maybe this is stone or something but you get the idea):

[image: This is one of the only pictures I was able to find on the internet that looked like the combo I'm thinking of-- tile walls & bench with acrylic base.]

Comment: `I don't see anyone adding a tile bench` .. probably because it is too cold for sitting on

Comment: They're pretty common. I think they're just usually used when doing an all-tile shower (tile floors, walls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the bench meets the base it's the same as where the wall meets the base. so there's not going to be a problem there.

Comment: I agree and have put benches in showers. Make sure to have a slight angle so the bench drains. A really cool trick I have used is to used forced air heating to warm the bench (and even a couple of custom tile baths) I put the duct in this area and the register or grill to the right for your photo, tile will normally be several degrees cooler so the warm air used to heat the bath was great for keeping the tile warm. This worked the best on the shower bench but also helped to reduce hot water and keep the bath warm longer, the tubs with this that had showers were warm on the feet not cold.+